# Multiple Round Robin Directors in Varnish

Tags: varnish

I wants to configure desktop/mobile website under single varnish machine. Each website i.e. mobile version and desktop version has multiple web servers. So I am defining multiple directors like below

I am using varnish 5.X

```
backend wap1 { .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; .port = "80"; 
.connect_timeout = 5s; .first_byte_timeout = 5s; .between_bytes_timeout = 2s; }
backend wap2 { .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; .port = "80"; 
.connect_timeout = 5s; .first_byte_timeout = 5s; .between_bytes_timeout = 2s; }

backend web1 { .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; .port = "80"; 
.connect_timeout = 5s; .first_byte_timeout = 5s; .between_bytes_timeout 
= 2s; }
backend web2 { .host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"; .port = "80"; 
.connect_timeout = 5s; .first_byte_timeout = 5s; .between_bytes_timeout 
= 2s; }

sub vcl_init {
new active_wap_rr = directors.round_robin();
new active_web_rr = directors.round_robin();
active_wap_rr.add_backend(wap1);
active_wap_rr.add_backend(wap2);
active_web_rr.add_backend(web1);
active_web_rr.add_backend(web2);
}

if (req.http.host == "m.example.com") {
    set req.backend_hint = active_wap_rr.backend();
}else if(req.http.host == "www.example.com" || req.http.host == "example.com") {
    set req.backend_hint = active_web_rr.backend();
}
```

Now when I do POST request in desktop version it sends to mobile site director while GET requests working fine.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was happing because of following code

```
if (req.host == "m.example.com") {
    if(req.method == "POST"){
          return (pass);
    }
}else if (req.host == "www.example.com" || req.host == "example.com") {
      if(req.method == "POST"){
          return (pass);
      }
 }
```

And below code assigns the backend hint

```
if (req.http.host == "m.example.com") {
    set req.backend_hint = active_wap_rr.backend();
}else if(req.http.host == "www.example.com" || req.http.host == 
"example.com") {
    set req.backend_hint = active_web_rr.backend();
}
```

While checking POST method and returning pass to backend no backend hint defined so it was taking first defined backend.

Correct way is

```
if (req.host == "m.example.com") {
    set req.backend_hint = active_wap_rr.backend();
    if(req.method == "POST"){
          return (pass);
    }
}else if (req.host == "www.example.com" || req.host == "example.com") {
      set req.backend_hint = active_web_rr.backend();
      if(req.method == "POST"){
          return (pass);
      }
 }
```

And below code is not required to assign backend.